# Where is all documents view in the site template?

Tags: list-view, site-definition

I got the task to update tons of site templates: add the column "Modified" to all views of all lists in all document libraries.
Of course, I won't do this by hand.
So I downloaded the templates, extracted them, and I found the views in the Schema.xml files for each list. With a mass find & replace I added the `<FieldRef Name="Modified" />` row to all `<ViewFields>` collection.
Repacked one, uploaded the template and created a site. Looks like everyting works, except one view: All Documents. I did not find this view in any of the Schema.xml files in the template. Could someone tell me, where can I find the definition of this view?

Edited: Is it possible that the view is defined inside a webpart?

```
<View List="CustomerDocs" DisplayName="All Documents" Url="" DefaultView="TRUE" BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartOrder="3" WebPartZoneID="Main" ContentTypeID="0x" ID="g_03e0ac65_f969_400b_a179_bb112fcc016e" Hidden="FALSE">
<BinarySerializedWebPart>
```

And after this a few other tags, then a long encrypted text like `View="qKkwMQwAAAAxAQAAeJxtj1..."`
My guess was that the webpart only refers to a view that is defined in somewhere else, but now to me, it looks like, that the Elements.xml that contains the definition for AllItems.aspx contains the view definition as well, encrypted inside the webpart code... Can this be right? And if yes, what is the fastest way to update 100+ of these templates?

Thank you,
vm

Comment: Is there an AllItems?

Comment: There is a reference to that in ListInstances\Files\_catalogs\masterpage\Schema.xml but that is for the All Master Pages view.
Modules\Elements.xml there is a reference to the All Documents view, but I did not fin any definition.